# Вопрос по заголовкам и нумерации

Tags: ms-word

Версия ворда - 2013. Думаю, подойдут и решения из 2010.

Не получается нормально настроить нумерацию заголовков. Постараюсь показать на примере, что не так, потому что не знаю как грамотно объяснить.

Создаю многоуровневый нумерованный список такого вида:

1.
1.1.
1.1.1.....

Начинаю создавать сам список. Пишу текст, нажимаю интер, появляется следующая циферка с новой строки. Нажимаю *Таб*, циферка 2 меняется на 1.1. Ввожу текст, снова жму интер. С новой строки появляется 1.2. Нажимаю снова интер, 1.2. меняется на 2. Короче в итоге получается такой текст

1. Текст

   1.1. Текст
2. Текст

   2.1 Текст

Все вроде бы норм, но мне нужно оглавление, причем динамическое. Для этого к элементам списка нужно применять стили заголовков. При применении стандартных стилей заголовков пропадает нумерация, потому что она в них не задана. Поэтому ставлю курсор на первой строке (1.) и нажимаю *"создать стиль"*. К нему сразу применяется нумерация текущей строки. Так же я наследую его от стиля *"Заголовок 1"*. В итоге у меня получается новый стиль, который идентичен заголовку 1, но с нумерацией. То же самое делаю со стилем *"Заголовок 2"*. И все, казалось бы, хорошо, НО!

Когда я к строке 2.1 применяю стиль, основанный на "заголовок 2", меняется нумерация с 2.1 на 1.2. То есть он как бы продолжает нумерацию прошлого заголовка 2 уровня (1.1.).

Как мне это исправить? Что нужно настроить в стилях заголовков, чтобы нумерация была правильной древовидной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> При применении стандартных стилей заголовков пропадает нумерация, потому что она в них не задана.

В настройках стандартных стилей заголовков доступна нумерация.
Но удобнее будет использовать многоуровневый список из встроенной библиотеки списков.

На вкладке меню `"Главная"`: `"Абзац"` -> `"Многоуровневый список"` -> `"Библиотека списков"` -> выбрать стиль списка.

[image: пример]

При добавлении новых заголовков (применении к тексту стандартных стилей заголовков) этот стиль списка будет применен к ним автоматически.